# Fixed Size Screen Element

Tags: android, android-layout

I attempted to make a simple app to see if I could make an element a fixed size, in this case 4cm wide, regardless of device. To do this I tried to use the screen xDPI, use that as an inch, multiply that by a constant to get 4cm. It doesn't appear this is working after trying it on a few different devices.

```
    final WindowManager w = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
    final DisplayMetrics m = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(m);

    //find the correct x density and multiply it by 1.5748 to get 4cm
    float density = m.xdpi;
    density = (float) (density * 1.5748);
    int intDensity = (int)Math.ceil(density);

    //now set the view to be the dimensions that you want, it must be inside of it's own layout?
    box.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(intDensity,100));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what dpi is for

Comment: Thanks, after taking another look it does look like everything is working better than I had initially thought. Because I hardcoded the height it appeared different to my eye on different density screens.

Comment: Ok nice, dimensions related issues can be really harsh on android :/